# Delete elements from one array when other array is false Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a question regarding python magic.
I have to arrays the same size. One filled with points and the other is a boolean array (true|false). Now I want to delete all points from the first array where the element is false in the other array.

So if my first array is [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)] and the other array is [true, false, false, true] the result array shall be [(1,2), (4,5)].

The problem is, that the arrays are quite big and the iterative method is pretty slow.

Does someone knows some numpy magic to execute this task pythonesque?

Comment: Use the bool array as the index? `first_array[bool_array]`

Comment: Your 1st "array" looks like a list of tuples, not a Numpy array. And you should use `False` and `True` for boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

it's straightforward with `numpy`

```
# convert your arrays to ndarrays
a = np.array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)])
mask = np.array([True, False, False, True])

print a[mask].tolist()
# [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Whats about the performance? Does it do the same like iterating over the elements?

Comment: I've made some tests with your example, and it seems that it's 3 times SLOWER than the list comprehension solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just take what you want , don't delete it: , One line solution without any external lib

```
print([first_1[i] for i,j in enumerate(second_1) if j==True])
```